# Correct way of implementation of: DAO Design Pattern php+pdo

Tags: php

```
class UserMapper {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function save(User $user_object)
    {

    }


    public function getUserById($id)
    {
        //code
    }


}

class User {

    private $id;
    private $username;

    function __construct($user_row = null) 
    {
        if (!is_null($user_row)) {
            $this->id = $user_row->id;
            $this->username = $user_row->username;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }

}
```

Example:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'New Username';
$user_mapper = new UserMapper($db); //Pdo object = $db
$user_mapper->save($user);
```

Is this the correct way of implenting the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's about it but there's more to the pattern .You might want to check out this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0301-dao.html) and [these](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0301-dao.html#resources) references, the pattern is explained in depth there.